# How to add google remote to a headless docker on vast

Tags: 16.04, headless

I want to add a GUI to a headless docker that I'm renting on vastai. It is using a cuda 16.04 docker image

I start by updating and upgrading and then

I followed this guide https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine selected xfce

I got the code as suggested by when I run the script

```
DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="mycodes" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)
```

Output: 
Refusing to run /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host

How do I change the user to one that would be able to run chrome remote desktop

I have added a user

```
adduser gamer
usermod -aG chrome-remote-desktop gamer
```

I tried running it as user

```
runuser -l gamer -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="mycodes" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=$(hostname)'
```

output
[0429/133320.745672:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_builtin.cc(559)] No net_fetcher for performing AIA chasing.
Couldn't start host: OAuth error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: Couldn't start host: OAuth error.

It is not working , because Google changed something and right now Chrome Remote Desktop do not support OSLogin feature - this info shows up in docs.
To resolve this problem just disable OSLogin on instance.

PS. But Chrome Remote Desktop still works thought IAP, so your instance do not need External IP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working. Im not sure where I went wrong before but in the end everything came together. I did a blog post on it. You can see the complete instruction in the link http://cryptolabs.co.za/2020/04/30/how-to-rendering-blender-eevee-on-a-headless-system/

I used this bashscript the install what I needed.

```
 $bash -c 'apt -y update; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends;   apt-get install -y gdebi; apt-get install -y gnupg2; apt-get install -y fonts-noto-cjk; apt-get install -y pulseaudio; apt-get install -y supervisor;   apt-get install -y x11vnc;  apt-get install -y fluxbox; apt-get install -y eterm; wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb; dpkg --install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb; wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub; wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; dpkg --install chrome-remote-desktop_current_amd64.deb; apt-key add /tmp/linux_signing_key.pub; dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt install --assume-yes --fix-broken; apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/cache/* /var/log/apt/* /var/lib/apt/lists/*;useradd -m -G chrome-remote-desktop,pulse-access chrome;usermod -s /bin/bash chrome; ln -s /crdonly /usr/local/sbin/crdonly; ln -s /update /usr/local/sbin/update;mkdir -p /home/chrome/.config/chrome-remote-desktop;mkdir -p /home/chrome/.fluxbox'
```

Next we install the Xfce desktop environment.

```
$echo ' \n\
    session.screen0.toolbar.visible:        false\n\
    session.screen0.fullMaximization:       true\n\
    session.screen0.maxDisableResize:       true\n\
    session.screen0.maxDisableMove: true\n\
    session.screen0.defaultDeco:    NONE\n\
' >> /home/chrome/.fluxbox/init
$chown -R chrome:chrome /home/chrome/.config /home/chrome/.fluxbox



$DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
apt update
apt upgrade
#apt install --assume-yes xfce4 desktop-base
$bash -c 'echo "exec /etc/X11/Xsession /usr/bin/xfce4-session" > /etc/chrome-remote-desktop-session'
$apt install --assume-yes xscreensaver
```

Just to be sure we want to stop lightdm.serves from running. There is no display connected to your instance, so the display manager service won’t start

```
$systemctl disable lightdm.service
```

Configuring and starting the Chrome Remote Desktop service

To start the remote desktop server, you need to have an authorization key for the Google account that you want to use to connect to it.

1 On your local computer, using the Chrome browser, go to the Chrome Remote Desktop command line setup page:https://remotedesktop.google.com/headless

2 If you’re not already signed in, sign in with a Google Account. This is the account that will be used for authorizing remote access.

3 On the Set up another computer page, click Begin.

4. On the Download and install Chrome Remote Desktop page, click Next.

5 Click Authorize. You need to allow Chrome Remote Desktop to access your account. If you approve, the page displays a command line for Debian Linux that looks like the following:

```
runuser -l chrome -c 'DISPLAY= /opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/start-host --code="4/yourcode" --redirect-url="https://remotedesktop.google.com/_/oauthredirect" --name=VastInstance'
```

Enter the pin as requested You should see an output “Host ready to receive connections.”

Connecting to the instance

You can connect to the instance using the Chrome Remote Desktop web application.

1. On your local computer, go to the Chrome Remote Desktop web site. https://remotedesktop.google.com/
2. Click Remote Access
3. If you’re not already signed in to Google, sign in with the same Google Account that you used to set up the Chrome Remote Desktop service. You see your new instance in the Remote Devices list.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It just so much information needed to get tho this part.